# Powershell: read computer monitor size from WMI script then write in a list

Tags: powershell, wmi

I need to get a list of Monitor resolution Sizes. I found this Script [here]. (http://poshcode.org/4688). It works properly on a single Computer. but I want to modify this script to import a list of clients and then export a csv list including the possible resolution sizes on every client of the imported list..

```
param($ComputerName = 'COMPUTERNAME')

$output = [PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName = $ComputerName;MonitorSizes=''}

$oWmi = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'rootwmi' -ComputerName $ComputerName
-Query "SELECT MaxHorizontalImageSize,MaxVerticalImageSize FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams"; $sizes = @(); if ($oWmi.Count -gt 1) {
    foreach ($i in $oWmi) {
        $x = [System.Math]::Pow($i.MaxHorizontalImageSize/2.54,2)
        $y = [System.Math]::Pow($i.MaxVerticalImageSize/2.54,2)
        $sizes += [System.Math]::Round([System.Math]::Sqrt($x + $y),0)
    }##endforeach } else {
    $x = [System.Math]::Pow($oWmi.MaxHorizontalImageSize/2.54,2)
    $y = [System.Math]::Pow($oWmi.MaxVerticalImageSize/2.54,2)
    $sizes += [System.Math]::Round([System.Math]::Sqrt($x + $y),0) }##endif

$output.MonitorSizes = $sizes

$output
```

Example Results:

ComputerName                                                                                           MonitorSizes
------------                                                                                           ------------
COMPUTERNAME                                                                                                  {15, 24}

ComputerName                                                                                           MonitorSizes
------------                                                                                           ------------
PC1                                                                                                  {19}

Comment: `I want to change it to import a computerlist and export to a csv` - OK, what exactly is stopping you?

Comment: I want to scan multiple Computer and add a loop to use more than one computer. Then export the result to textfile

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy in PowerShell. Simply wrap your code in a `foreach` loop and iterate over one or more computer names:

```
param(
    [string[]]$ComputerName
)

foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){

    $oWmi = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi' -ComputerName $Computer -Query "SELECT MaxHorizontalImageSize,MaxVerticalImageSize FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams"; 
    $sizes = @() 
    if ($oWmi.Count -gt 1) 
    {
        foreach ($i in $oWmi) {
            $x = [System.Math]::Pow($i.MaxHorizontalImageSize/2.54,2)
            $y = [System.Math]::Pow($i.MaxVerticalImageSize/2.54,2)
            $sizes += [System.Math]::Round([System.Math]::Sqrt($x + $y),0)
        }##endforeach
    }else{
        $x = [System.Math]::Pow($oWmi.MaxHorizontalImageSize/2.54,2)
        $y = [System.Math]::Pow($oWmi.MaxVerticalImageSize/2.54,2)
        $sizes += [System.Math]::Round([System.Math]::Sqrt($x + $y),0) 
    }##endif

    New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{ComputerName = $Computer; MonitorSizes = $sizes}
}
```

Assuming you save it to a file called `GetMonitorSizes.ps1`, you would use it like this:

```
$Names = "server1","server2","server3"
.\GetMonitorSizes.ps1 -ComputerName $Names
```

or if you have a file with a computer name on each line:

```
$Names = Get-Content '\\server\list.txt'
.\GetMonitorSizes.ps1 -ComputerName $Names
```

You can also pipe the resulting objects to a CSV file with the `Export-Csv` cmdlet:

```
.\GetMonitorSizes.ps1 -ComputerName $Names | Export-Csv .\screensizes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Sorry, but how I add computers in there? I tried  $ComputerName = Get-Content  '\\server\list.txt' in the first row.

Comment: @user5193276 Updated the answer, see usage example

Comment: 1. ComputerName                                                                      MonitorSizes                                                                    
------------                                                                      ------------                                                                    
PC216,PC109                                                                       {0}                 

2. Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: @user5193276 Usually an indication that the firewall (or DCOM+) on the remote machine doesn't permit remote WMI queries. Google the error ("The RPC server is unavailable") and you should find a wealth of troubleshooting information

Comment: At first the original script worked at remote computers.

Comment: I tried first your method
weird Result:
ComputerName                                                                      MonitorSizes                                                                    
------------                                                                      ------------                                                                    
PC216,PC109                                                                       {0}

Comment: @user5193276 Well, as you can see from the first usage example, it still does. What does the contents of your `\\server\list.txt` look like?

Comment: @user5193276 There's a typo in your question, namespace should be `root\wmi`, not `rootwmi`, updated answer

Comment: Yes, thanks, there was this typo. $Names = Get-Content '\\server\list.txt'
.\GetMonitorSizes.ps1 -ComputerName $Names worked for me. I tried  now with pipelining and the content of the first row PC216,"System.Object[]"